# How do I further reduce a SearchQuerySet based on a common M2M attribute

Tags: django, django-haystack

How do I further reduce a SearchQuerySet based on a common M2M attribute such that I can query for all objects where sky = blue?

Assign ObjectA:

```
 Property → property_definition = "sky" value = "blue"
 Property → property_definition = "current_color" value = "red"
```

Assign ObjectB:

```
 Property → property_definition = "sky" value = "red"
 Property → property_definition = "current_color" value = "blue"
```

This should result in one and only one answer (ObjectA) but I'm getting 2 because the templates are seeing both properties.

Can anyone shed some light as to how to narrow these results.   Because SearchQuerySet doesn't suppport remove() I can't post process them and I can't think of a clean way to do this??

Help Please!!

```
--- models.py ---

DATA_CHOICES = ((u'string', u'string'), (u'integer', u'integer'),                (u'real', u'real'), (u'boolean', u'boolean'))


class PropertyDefinition(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    datatype = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=DATA_CHOICES)

class Property(models.Model):
    property_definition = models.ForeignKey(PropertyDefinition)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class ObjectA(models.Model):
    properties = model.ManyToManyField(Property)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)

class ObjectB(models.Model):
    properties = model.ManyToManyField(Property)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)


--- search_indexes.py ---
class ObjectAIndex(indexes.BasicSearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):   
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')

    def get_model(self):
        return ObjectA

class ObjectBIndex(ObjectAIndex):
    def get_model(self):        
        return ObjectB


--templates (identical but named appropriately )--

{{object.name}}
{% for property in object.properties %}
    {{ property.property_definition.name }} {{ property.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, why not

```
class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    datatype = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=DATA_CHOICES)
```

then, assuming the above model:

```
ObjectA.objects.filter(properties__name='sky', properties__value='blue')
```

third, your object model does not allow you to get both types of objects in the same query set. I would combine `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` into the same model.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work

```
a = ObjectA.properties.filter(name = Your_name)
b = a.property_definition.filter(value = Your_Value)
```

Maybe not exactly like the above, but the general idea is you want to chain them togethor and drill down to get what you want in each chain.